# Looking for concise and precise terms for feedback rating options

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am designing a user reputation system that will be an essential piece of an online marketplace for peer-to-peer item rentals. The user reputation system is based on the collection of feedbacks given by users reviewing the transactions they had with other users. Each feedback is consisted of a three-valued rating and an optional detailed comment. The three rating options are:

- Beyond expectations
- As expected and with understandable/tolerable hiccups, if any. (implicit)
- Terrible

Our approach is to ask users to leave rating only for those experiences that are beyond expectations or terrible. That's why I have labelled, above, the neutral rating as implicit.

I am leaning towards using the term **bummer** to denote *terrible experience*. To a reviewer, **bummer* represents her disappointment while having less negativity, comparing to the word *terrible*, to the viewers.

1. Is *bummer* an appropriate term choice for my case?
2. If yes, what is a better alternative for *"beyond expectations"* that would go well with *bummer*?

Comment: If you want casual terms on a par with "bummer" (which may be somewhat outdated by now—it emerged in the '60s, I believe):  _Lame, Shoddy, Crummy, Sucks_.  For the positive side:  _awesome, fabulous, fantastic, perfect, great, unbeatable, excellent_.  ....... By the way, say "default value" rather than  "implicit".  (The radio button for this middle option would, I presume, be selected by default.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my opinion, but the word *bummer* seems a bit too informal for this context, and it might make it hard for some users to take your ratings seriously.

I think *disappointing* might be a better word, the opposite of which could be *stellar*:

- Stellar
- As expected
- Disappointing

Comment: J.R. - Thanks. I think you have brought up a good point. I like your choice of words.